# one controller, service and model instance per request in node js

Tags: node.js, javascript-objects, es6-class

I am working on a large project and we are reviewing the performance of the system we are thinking to make one(separate) instance of controller, service and model for every single request to make the code more readable but I think it would affect the performance of the system!!
Is it so?

Comment: can you elaborate more on this. Unlike c# or java, you dont usually have mv* frameworks in node js.
The only explicit mvc framework i know of in node js is sail.js .

what do you mean by separate instance ?most node "app" instances are singleton